# Finding out whether a function is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

In "[Thomas' calculus](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/thomas13einfo/)", there's a given physical application of the *Mean Value Theorem* in which it asks us why would a vehicle be cited for speeding with $65$mph when it had covered $159$ miles in $2$ hours.

In this case, the mean value theorem could explain that at a point within it's domain the average velocity is equal to the velocity at that point, the problem is:

> How do we figure out that the function is continuous on $[a, b]$ and
> differentiable on $(a, b)$?
> Or, how do we know in a real life that the function is continous?

EDIT: I'm particularly confused at the point where our conclusion reaches that the body is continuous. The average velocity would obviously be greater if the body braked at some point, right? Or, if the body made some sudden stops in the interval of it's domain, how is it assumed that the body is continuous?

Comment: I don't know if you are looking for an intuitive explanation, but from that perspective his car can't suddenly jump ahead distance or disappear at any given time, so the function of his position has to be continuous. For differentiability, cars can't stop or accelerate instantaneously, so there can't be sharp points that would make the function nondifferentiable.

Comment: @Tyberius: They can stop instantaneously -- if they hit a wall... :-)

Comment: @zipirovich But even hitting a wall isn't an instantaneous deceleration, though it might look like it if your time scale is in minutes or even seconds.

Comment: @Tyberius: I'm gonna take your word for it. I'm certainly not going to try it myself. :-)

Comment: @Tyberius , I'm looking at the rare possibility that the car made a, well, a stop for say _dt_ seconds and then made his way to the destination in the time i.e. 159 miles in 2 hours(if he did sped up real fast), he would break the speed limit, yes, but, the function of this motion would not be continous, right?

Answer (score 3):

In real life, functions *are* continuous and differentiable. Even better, they are bounded, and so are their derivatives.

In particular, the acceleration of a vehicle is limited by the available torque of its engine (strong - but finite - deceleration can be caused by hitting a wall), so that the speed never changes instantly. The speed itself is limited (even in free fall), and obviously the position cannot be discontinuous.

Physical phenomena are described by smooth curves, and in usual circumstances, very smooth.

---

On another hand, all phenomena are subject to perturbations (for instance ambient noise causes vibrations), so that all curves are irregular when you magnify them. For this reason, high order derivatives are dominated by noise and are meaningless.

Comment: "In real life, functions _are_ continuous and differentiable.", That's exactly what I'm asking, **How**?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: that's exactly whay I am answering, did you read ? Discontinuities require infinite energy.

Comment: I did read it, but your sentence implies _in general_ not just in the case of the vehicle

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: this vehicle has presumably nothing different from all vehicles on Earth.

Comment: I'm looking at the possibility that the car made, a stop for say dt seconds and then made his way to the destination in the time i.e. 159 miles in 2 hours(if he did sped up real fast), he would break the speed limit, yes, but, the function of this motion would not be continous, right?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: in an idealised world where discontinuities are possible, yes. Your question was about the real life.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust , You mean, _every real life functions are continuous and differentiable_ ? Where do I know more about this? Is this sort of concepts in higher level calculus? Please give me some book recommendations if so. (I'm self studying calculus from Thomas' calculus, and such concepts are not well explained). Where do we end up proving that all real life functions are continuous?

Comment: Real life is described by physics, not by calculus.

Comment: Where do we prove in physics that every real life functions are continuous?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: you don't meet infinity in real life. Inertia.

Comment: I've just about lost every clues of a notion of even the slightest understanding. You mentioned, " In real life functions are continuous and differentiable", I was just seeking a proof for that particular statement. I mean a function may not only be that of a motion, it may be some other value relating two entities.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x=c$ then, it means that the function is continuous at that point. A necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to be differentiable at $x=c$ is that

$$f′(c) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(c + h) − f(c)}h$$

Note that there are three things that *have to be true* for a function to be continuous at some value $c$ in the domain $[a,b]$:

- $f(c)$ must be defined, meaning that the function must exist at $x$ value $(x=c)$, which imply you can’t have a "hole" in the function at that point such as a $0$ in the denominator, for example.

$$f(c)\,:\,c\in[a,b]$$

- The limit of the function as $x$ approaches the value $c$ must exist. That means that the left and right limits must be the same. In other words, the function has to be "smooth", it can’t have a hole, a "sharp" edge (like $|x|$ at $x=0$) or an asymptote at $c$.

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \;\text{must exist.}$$

- The limit as $x$ approaches $c$ must be the same as the value of the function at $c$.

$$f(c)=\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$$

---

You mention the mean value theorem in your question. You may (or may not) know the fact that these considerations of continuity are what yield the *mean value theorem of the differential calculus* or the *law of the mean of the differential calculus* which definitely is of considerable use.

See, when relying upon geometric evidence to prove

$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a),\quad a\lt c\lt b$$

we must make some assumptions:

- First, $f(x)$ *must be continuous* on $x\in[a,b]$ (where $[a,b]$ need not be small).

In case $f$ *is not* continuous on $[a,b]$ then there is no value of $x$ in the domain for which the slope of the function $f$ is equal to the slope of the chord $AB$ joining the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

- Secondly, the function $f$ *must have a definite slope* at every point in the domain $[a,b]$. In other words, $f'(x)$ *must exist* at every point in the domain.

If there was to be an infinite acceleration, the limit would not exist at that point and the graph would change abruptly. Therefore, the function would fail to take on enough values between $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ to yield a point on the curve where the slope of the function $f$ equals the slope of the secant $AB$.

Since (as pointed out by others), infinite accelerations can only happen *theoretically*, you can feel safe about *assuming* that functions describing physical phenomena are continuous and "smooth".

On a final note, there is a special case where $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ both equal zero which makes $f'(c)(b-a) = 0$ and leads to a special result known as [*Rolle's theorem*](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY94fF3-_SAhUCi1QKHbYHCbsQFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRolle's_theorem&usg=AFQjCNGEmPBh_XbgMmRjC5sKiw2IzEjQKA).

Comment: The OP is asking why a specific real world example is continuous and differentiable, not asking for a general explanation of continuity.

Comment: @Jason OP asked "how do we figure out that the function is continuous on 
[a,b] and differentiable on (a.b)?" which is exactly what I adressed in my answer thus, I do not think that my answer should be downvoted.

Comment: But you have only really given basic definitions, with no real reference to this specific question. At the very least, if you are answering "how to verify a function is continuous/differentiable" you should provide some general techniques as to how one would approach such a problem.

Comment: @Jason Point taken, I see what you mean and I would agree with you if there was evidence on OP's part of some work on this (homework/assignment looking) problem. I would have edited my answer to provide examples and further content if at the very least there was some interest form OP in the comments and replies to the question. Hence, my intention here was to provide clarifications on these important definitions and I maintain that my answer is appropriate since again, OP's original post asked about those definitions specifically (in boldface, in the original format of the question).

Comment: @Jason , Yes, that was exactly what I meant, I wanted to know how it is possible to figure out in real world why functions would be continuous right? Do we take the ideal cases that example that the body was in a continous motion? I mean the average velocity would be greater if the body braked at a certain time, right?